# In Coq how to combine two hypothesis or rearrange the parenthesis in subgoals

Tags: coq

I am having a problem with proving a subgoal using two hypotheses.
I had:

```
subgoals
r1, r2 : rexp
IHr1 : matches_nil (Cat r1 r1) = matches_nil r1
IHr2 : matches_nil (Cat r2 r2) = matches_nil r2
______________________________________(1/3)
matches_nil (Cat (Cat r1 r2) (Cat r1 r2)) =
matches_nil (Cat r1 r2)
```

Then I used simply. on the subgoal and the hypotheses:

```
subgoals
r1, r2 : rexp
IHr1 : matches_nil r1 && matches_nil r1 =
       matches_nil r1
IHr2 : matches_nil r2 && matches_nil r2 =
       matches_nil r2
______________________________________(1/3)
matches_nil r1 && matches_nil r2 &&
(matches_nil r1 && matches_nil r2) =
matches_nil r1 && matches_nil r2
```

I thought the two hypotheses now are enough to prove the subgoal. But what tactic should I use?
I'd appreciate any instructions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to consider the different values a boolean expression can have by using the `destruct` tactic to destruct the boolean values `matches_nil r1` and `matches_nil r2` that occur in the goal into being `true` or `false`.

So perhaps try `destruct (matches_nil r1), (matches_nil r2); simpl in *.`  This will give you four new goals to solve.

By the way, in this part of your proof the hypotheses does not really contain any useful information, they are essentially `true=true`, (which shouldn't come as a shocker :-)).

--

Otherwise you can rewrite your goal with i.e. `andb_comm` and `andb_diag`.  To find lemmas that deal with `andb` (that you write with the notation `&&`) you can do `Search andb.` and you will get a list of lemmas that are in the modules you have imported from the standard library.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just found that there was no need to use the induction. I think that is why the IHs are not really useful. But your answer really gave me a new way to think and I solved it! Thank you so much!